# sending AT command with NCK code unlock sim?

Tags: command-line

I need information. How can I send the NCK unlock code network using AT commands? Or is there any other ways?

Comment: Depends on the who made the phone and the AT command set they support. I did this recently on a ZTE Modem using AT+ZNCK I believe, but that command isn't a standard one across all manufacturers! Trying to do it again on an LG, no good luck so far.

Comment: look. on any phone has an interface for inputting code NCK. this is a normal apk. I decompiled it and looked at the code for my Micromax Q415, there was PhoneFactory.getDefaultPhone (). getIccCard (). supplyDepersonalization (). This method nck code sent to the modem. but I could not find how he does it. I can either call this method and learn how it works and do the same. I'm right?

Comment: Look like AT+CLCK is the closest thing to a standard way across manufacturers. But again, the actual name of the lock varies by manufacturer. I'm trying to unlock a JAVA-based feature phone, can't use API.

Comment: What is he doing  `supplyDepersonalization`, if AT+CLCK absend ? I can't find. How to find out?